# How do I put an asterisk for mandatory fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

how do I put a red asterisk on a mandatory  field ?
For example `title`, `location`, `Name`, `Email` (for `Owner` section), `Name`,`Email` are required (*) and the `Age` and `Location` are optional

```
export default function App() {
  // ...
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
     
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <span className="mr-3 h-6 text-md font-bold  leading-8 text-gray-500">
          Title:
        </span>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={title}
          placeholder="title"
          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <span className="mr-3 h-6 text-md font-bold  leading-8 text-gray-500">
          Location:
        </span>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={location}
          placeholder="Location"
          onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
        />
    //...
  );
}
```

Here what I'm saying in a picture :
[image]

Comment: Put an asterix next to the fields?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question and add some precision !

Answer (score 1):

Give all of your label elements a class of `required` and add the following to your CSS:

```
.required::after {
    content: " *";
    color: red;
}
```

working example:

```css
form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 300px;
}

.required::after {
    content: " *";
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label class="required" for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" class="field req" type="text" required>
</form>
```

Comment: This won't work if `.required` is put on inputs

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/jgorelik23/u0a8jb5q/2/ Also, I don't get your point, change the className then, lol.